# Angular 2 module import breaking app

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm doing the quickstart tutorial and am encountering some error. The following is my file structure:

```
//## home/home.component.ts #################
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector:'home',
  template: `
<div>I'm a home component.</div>
`
})

export class HomeComponent{}

//## home/home.module.ts #################
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";

NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: [HomeComponent]
});

export class HomeModule {
}

//## app.component.ts #################
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div>I'm the App Component</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}

//## app.module.ts #################
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {HomeModule} from "./home/home.module"; //this breaks it

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HomeModule] //home module breaks it
})

export class AppModule{}

//## main.ts #################
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {AppModule} from "./app.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I am confused, as this is a pretty simple example. The Home module is causing the application to fail somehow. It gives the following error:

`ZoneAwareErrormessage: "(SystemJS) Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined ...` followed by hundreds of lines of the same. Does anyone have any ideas on how to debug errors like these?

Comment: Does changing declarations: [AppComponent], to declarations: [BrowserModule, HomeModule], change something?

Comment: @SebastienDErrico no unfortunately not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coudn't fix this, but for anyone experiencing the same problem, avoid the quickstart tutorial and use angular-cli to generate things instead. It seems much cleaner and easier to understand when starting out.

`ng new new-project --style=sass` should sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

If HomeModule is a feature module, change your declaration section to be  `declarations: [CommonModule, HomeComponent]`

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error,and it's cause the zone find some error in my template. I'm in Angular 2.4.1 and zone 0.7.4,try upgrade.

btw,I had set the template property to the url of my template,it's work,so,I think the zone may has a bug or something.

Answer (score 0):

You must import [CommonModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CommonModule-class.html) in the HomeModule. Your HomeModule code will be like this:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";  // Add this
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";

NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],  // Add this
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: [HomeComponent]
});

export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem for me. What does CommonModule do here?

Comment: CommonModule is a subset of BrowserModule (the one you use in AppModule) and you must import it in all feature modules. More information about [CommonModule here in Angular2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#imports)

Comment: @userqwert Also see this FAQ on Angular docs - [Should I import BrowserModule or CommonModule?](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-browser-vs-common-module)